# Ubuntu grep does not remove unwanted lines

Tags: ubuntu, grep

On ubuntu, i search for "ubuntu" locations

```
find / -name ubuntu
```

I get lots of lines with "Permission denied"
I try to remove the lines

```
find / -name ubuntu | grep -v Permission
```

I still get the unwanted lines

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

It's because the errors from `find` are going to stderr. You can redirect stderr to stdout as well and then the filtering with grep would work.

```
find / -name ubuntu 2>&1 | grep -v Permission
```

1 represents standard output and 2 represents standard error. `2>&1` denotes "redirect stderr to wherever stdout goes".